# "Failed to retrieve the server version" error when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was just developling some test code, just a few lines, when suddently this error appears:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -55
>   [code] => -55 [2] => Failed to retrieve the server version. Unable to
>   continue. [message] => Failed to retrieve the server version. Unable
>   to continue. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] =>
>   5701 [code] => 5701 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'test'. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'test'. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 01000
>   [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5703 [code] => 5703 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]L'impostazione della lingua è
>   stata sostituita con Italiano. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]L'impostazione della lingua è stata
>   sostituita con Italiano. ) )

So I deleted all the code done so far for testing only the connection with

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "test", "UID" => "testuser", "PWD" => "somepwd");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Then I opened Microsoft server SQL management studio for checking the DB and everything appears to be fine...
Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved by installing Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client.

Download the appropriate Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client for your structure at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065

Comment: This is an old thread, but since I forgot to post my solution i'll thank you for posting it. 
For everyone having the same problem, this solution is gonna work. Be sure to download the right version though